# Why is a call to a C++ struct's function ambiguous if there are inherited members with different parameters?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

The code is below. I have one single function f(), and one single function f(int) in my class D, so why is that call ambiguous if both functions have different parameters?

```
struct A {
    void f() {}
};

struct B: virtual A {
    void f(int i) {}
};

struct C: virtual A {
    void f() {}
};

struct D: B, C {

};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.f(5); //ambiguous
}
```

Comment: What does `A` have to do with your problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem here is with member name lookup, which occurs before evaluating which functions are viable and applying overload resolution.  When name lookup finds names from two or more unrelated base class, this is considered an ambiguous lookup, which is immediately invalid.

For more details, read about [unqualified name lookup in class member definitions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Member_function_definition).  (This is not actually the context you have here, but the same rules apply for a member access expression.)

You could work around this by specifying the base class where you want lookup to start, using a qualified-id:

```
d.B::f(5);
```

Or, you could make both functions explicitly visible directly in `D`:

```
struct D: B, C {
    using B::f;
    using C::f;
};
```

Comment: Wow, today I learned that `var.Class::method()` is legal syntax.

Comment: clang compiles without the using's, GCC not. Is clang's behavior wrong?

Comment: @BenjaminBuch What version of clang? 3.8.0 and 6.0.0 trunk 314645 both give me the "ambiguous name lookup" error on the program in the OP.

Comment: @aschepler replace f by operator(), didn't expect that it would make a difference … (I used trunk to test.)

Answer (score 1):

The call is ambiguous because both bases A and C of struct D have a function called `void f()`, even if A's `f()` is hidden.  To disambiguate, you should declare f() in D.

```
struct A {
    void f() {}
};

struct B: virtual A {
    void f(int i) {}   // <  hides A::f(), even if signature is different,
};

struct C: virtual A {
    void f() {}        // <  hides A::f()
};

struct D: B, C {
                       // f(...) functions in both base... which one hides the other?
};
```

Comment: Btw, I don't think it matters that `A` has `f()`.

Comment: it doesn't, I'm quite sure of it.